# Gwt i18n > generating properties files

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I'm using GWT in my stuff, and I would like to make it,
international, so I use GWT constants method.

I have a java file with defaults, and I now need to make properties files.

In a remember, there is a special thing to do (or done automagically) to generate 
a kind of template where all constants are generated with empty labels for other langages.

Did I dream this ?

(using eclipse indigo to develop webapp with gwt but not gae)

[edit:]

this was not a dream, it's i18ncreator:

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools.html#i18nCreator

but I can't make it working on windows :-(

[edit again ]

due to this issue :  http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5113

recommended solution is use i18ncreator in gwt 1.7  (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my project, I used the i18n-Creator

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuidePropertiesFiles

It kind of does the opposite of what you are asking for. With the i18n-creator, you create the properties files for the various locales and run the script that is generated with the i18n-creator, and it will generate the constants interface.

Answer (score 2):

you should see the page on [locales in GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was looking all over the place for the answer but could not find an answer; either in the docs or on stackoverflow.

So I asked in the GWT gitter channel and was told to use the compiler argument

`-extra <destination-folder-name>`

to generate the `.properties` files from the Interface files.

### Steps in eclipse:

1. Select project you want to compile
2. [right click] -> Google -> GWT Compile
3. In the window that opens, open the **Advanded** options.
4. Add the following additional compiler argument `-extra <destination-folder-name>`
5. Compile

[image: setting compiler option in eclipse to generate the extra files]

This should generate the `*.properties` files in the `/destination-folder-name`.

**NOTE:** This only generates the `.properties` files. It does not actually compile the application with all the locales for deploy.

6. Move the `MyInterfaceExtension_*.properties` to be right beside the `MyInterfaceExtension.java` file.
7. Make copies for each locale i.e. `MyInterfaceExtension_fr_CA.properties`, `MyInterfaceExtension_fr_FR.properties`, etc..
8. Translate them
9. Then run the compilation process again **with out** the `-extra <destination-folder-name>` option. Because it is not needed anymore.

This will compile with all the locales you enabled. You can now deploy the app the usual way.

### Quick Tips:

When compiling for the first time in order to generate the `.properties` file, I commented out the locales in the module definition file so that the compiler will not sit there and compile again and again for every browser and every locale

i.e. `supported_browser_count x enabled_locale_count` = 5 browsers x 3 locales = 15 compilation Permutations, which is going to increase your compilation time.

Because, all I needed was that one `*_en.properties` file.

For the second compilation, after you copied and translated the properties files for each locale, you have to enable all the locales you want to support and compile.

### Credits:

1. github @niloc132 : Colin Alworth
2. github @ibaca : Ignacio Baca Moreno-Torres

For helping me with this.

Comment: Is it working with GWT 2.9.0? I am trying to generate properties files without success

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard yet of this feature in Eclipse but IntelliJ IDEA has this feature, you just create the Constants Interface class and the properties file. If you add a method in the class file it will warn you to add the property or the other way around. HTH.